# FullCalendar Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssRules') SSR Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, server-side-rendering

I try to make an Angular app with SSR and FullCalendar but when I use the SSR command (`npm run dev:ssr)` I have the following error from the fullcalendar import module :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssRules')
    at appendStylesTo (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:164194:25)
    at /Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:164158:5
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at injectStyles (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:164157:12)
    at Module.88836 (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:164231:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/main.js:521:42)
    at Module.55354 (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:161639:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/main.js:521:42)
    at Module.42075 (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/vendor.js:160876:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/dotnetmael/Documents/testSSr/testSSR/dist/testSSR/server/main.js:521:42)
```

To be simple to try, I make a repo :
https://github.com/dotnetmael/fullcalendar-issue

Just follow the README and normally the error message is shown.

To reproduce the issue :

Take a project which use FullCalendarModule (example : https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/tree/main/angular15)

Create a new app in Angular 15 and add the @fullcalendar and @nguniversal/express-engine packages

```
{
  "name": "test-ssr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run testSSR:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/testSSR/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run testSSR:server",
    "prerender": "ng run testSSR:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Add domino to the server to avoid document is not defined error :

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Use the browser index.html as template for the mock window
const template = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join(join(process.cwd(), 'dist/testSSR/browser'), 'index.html'))
  .toString();

const window = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;
global['localStorage'] = window.localStorage;
global['navigator'] = window.navigator;
global['CSS'] = window.CSS;

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/testSSR/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Add CommonJS to the tsconfig.server :

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

Add full calendar to the app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FullCalendarModule} from "@fullcalendar/angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FullCalendarModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then try the `npm run dev:ssr` command

Comment: To anyone having the same issue, if you downgrade fullcalendar to 6.1.5 it works for me !